# Implementing read-lock and reading a file on a server or implemeting write lock and writing on a file on server

Tags: java, sockets, file-io

How can a file on a server be read or be written on by a client. What is the procedure for implementing read/write lock using sockets programming in Java? 
(If there is a post on stackoverflow that answers this question already please refer me to that because I cannot find it).

Comment: Too many questions here, all too vague, and all based on false assumptions. -1

Answer (score 0):

Sockets can't do that. They are merely a communication utility. Server and client talk to each other following some protocol (e.g. HTTP, FTP, your own).

If your Server allows to write files through socket based communication it must lock the file manually. How depends on factors like OS support for file locking, the language your server is written in, ..